# Can’t convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first

Tags: numpy, pytorch, gpu

I tried to this function

```
def multi_label_auroc(y_gt, y_pred):
    auroc = []
    gt_np = y_gt.cpu().numpy()
    pred_np = y_pred.cpu().numpy()
    assert gt_np.shape == pred_np.shape, "y_gt and y_pred should have the same size"
    for i in range(gt_np.shape[1]):
        try:
            auroc.append(roc_auc_score(gt_np[:, i], pred_np[:, i]))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return auroc
```

```
where : Parameters
    y_gt: torch.Tensor groundtruth
    y_pred: torch.Tensor prediction, Returns: list F1 of each class
```

But later in the training process i keep getting : `Can’t convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first`

I also tried to use: `y_gt.detach().cpu().numpy()` but it said : `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'detach'`

Can somemone please explain what to do

Update:

i realised that the problem was in this training function where the chart is being created:

```
def trainModel(modelname,loss_criteria,modeltxt):
    model = modelname(num_classes=len(LABELS),is_trained=True).to(device)

    optimizer = get_opt(modeltxt,model)
    # Learning rate will be reduced automatically during training
    lr_scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, factor = LEARNING_RATE_SCHEDULE_FACTOR,
                                                        patience = LEARNING_RATE_SCHEDULE_PATIENCE, mode = 'max', verbose=True)
    best_score = 0
    best_score_acc = 0
    best_score_f1 = 0
    
    model_path = out+modeltxt+".pth"
    out_path = out+modeltxt+"_running.csv"
    training_losses = []
    validation_losses = []
    validation_score = []
    validation_acc = []
    validation_f1 = []


    # Config progress bar
    mb = master_bar(range(MAX_EPOCHS))
    mb.names = ['Train loss', 'Val loss', 'AUROC', 'Accuracy', 'f1 score']

    x = []

    nonimproved_epoch = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    cnt = 1

    # Training each epoch
    for epoch in mb:
        #break
        mb.main_bar.comment = f'Best AUROC score: {best_score}'
        x.append(epoch)

        # Training
        train_loss = epoch_training(epoch, model, train_dataloader, device, loss_criteria, optimizer, mb)
        mb.write('Finish training epoch {} with loss {:.4f}'.format(epoch, train_loss))
        training_losses.append(train_loss)

        # Evaluating
        val_loss, new_score, new_score_acc, new_score_f1 = evaluating(epoch, model, val_dataloader, device, loss_criteria, mb)

        validation_losses.append(val_loss)
        validation_score.append(new_score)
        validation_acc.append(new_score_acc)
        validation_f1.append(new_score_f1)

        gc.collect()
        # Update learning rate
        lr_scheduler.step(new_score)

        # Update training chart
        mb.update_graph([[x, training_losses], [x, validation_losses], [x, validation_score] , [x, validation_acc] ,
                         [x, validation_f1]],
                        [0,epoch+1+round(epoch*0.3)], [0,1])

        diff = np.round(time.time() - start_time)
        pd.DataFrame([[epoch,modeltxt,best_score,new_score,diff]]).to_csv(out_path,index=False,mode='a',header=False)
```

I removed the part of updating the training chart and it ran smoothly but still, i need to solve the problem

Comment: Can you post the full traceback and error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provide the ***full*** error backtrace for both scenarios. It appears the two problems are raised in different parts of your code.

Comment: I've made updates